# show working image while executing h:commandlink action

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

To add an article, I have `<h:commandlink>` that executes an action which redirect to a success or error page depending on action results. The action takes a while to finish its execution, approximately 4 seconds. Could you tell me how to display a loading image when action begins to execute and hide it when action terminates?

Comment: Since your question is basically *Is it possible to ...* the correct answer would be *Yes, it is possible*.

Comment: "*display a loading image?*" If you insist upon using some rich component libraries like PrimeFaces then, these are : [`<p:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml), [`<pe:blockUI>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockUIAjax.jsf), [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml)

Comment: I have an answer but is meant to hide the gif after the processing was successful. I don't know how to send a redirect since I don't know ow to set the right data to w/o using a hack

Comment: I'm not asking for the redirect because I know How to do this.

Comment: I'm just asking to have something like onbegin and oncomplete for a4j:commandlink but I don't want to use richfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use ajax for the task at hand. Using plain vanilla JSF and some javascript, this would be the solution:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Submit" action="#{yourManagedBean.desiredAction}">
        <f:ajax onevent="showProgress" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <!-- other components... -->

    <!-- External div which wraps the loading gif -->
    <div id="divProgress" style="display: none; height: 60px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: text-top;">
            Working...
            <!-- Locate your gif wherever you stored -->
            <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/loading.gif" height="49" width="49" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showProgress(data) {
            var ajaxStatus = data.status;
            switch (ajaxStatus) {
                case "begin":
                    //This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
                    //Showing the div where the "loading" gif is located
                    document.getElementById("divProgress").style.display = 'table';
                    break;

                case "success":
                    //This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
                    //In your case, you will need to redirect to your success page
                    var url = window.location.protocol + "//"
                        + window.location.host + "/"
                        + (window.location.port ? ":"+ window.location.port: "");
                    window.location.href = url + "#{request.contextPath}/" + "#{yourManagedBean.resultUrl}";
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</h:form>
```

And in your managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class YourManagedBean {
    private String resultUrl;
    //getters and setters...
    public void desiredAction() {
        //do the processing...
        if (...) {
            resultUrl = "success.xhtml";
        } else {
            resultUrl = "error.xhtml";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort of answering, I did the same with onClick event of h:commandLink and it worked as I want it.